# Is there a Visual Studio Template for MVC and WebAPI Account Controllers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created a WebAPI project and now have the requirement to add the ability to have users register/sign-in and navigate Authorized Views in an ASP.NET MVC website.

I have now created a ASP.NET MVC Project and included the MVC and WebAPI checkboxes when creating the project. The result is I now have an ASP.NET MVC AccountController (with views etc) but no WebApi AccountController.

So my two questions are :

1. Is it Ok to just manually copy the WebAPI AccountController over to
   my new MVC Project?
2. Has anybody created and tested the scaffolding for this type of
       project already, so can easily download it as a template instead of
       doing it manually?

Please let me know your thoughts on how you would approach this, as maybe i am overlooking something.

Comment: And the reason for the downvote?

Comment: You want to copy/paste the web api controllers from one application to your mvc application? Stand by.

Comment: Yes - unless there is a template that already has both or it shouldn't be done for whatever reason.  I have had a look online but this solution doesn't appear much. Maybe i am overlloking something.

Comment: Specifically the AccountController that does the authentication etc.